Ryu controller not forwarding packet after changes in mininet topology
I had written a simple mininet code to make a topology that was working well with my controller logic. The topology I had was
h refers to host, of refers to openflow switch
h1 <-> of1
h2 <-> of2
h3 <-> of2
h4 <-> of3
of1 <-> of2
of2 <-> of3

After that I did the following changes to the topology, Below is Image and code for the mininet network that is not working now with same controller

import os
from mininet.log import info
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import RemoteController, OVSSwitch

def setup_network():
    net = Mininet(controller=RemoteController, switch=OVSSwitch, link=TCLink)

    # Add Ryu controller
    info('[+] Adding Ryu controller\n')
    c0 = net.addController('c0', controller=RemoteController)

    # Add switches, hosts, and links as before
    info('[+] Adding OpenFlow switches\n')
    of1 = net.addSwitch('of1')
    of2 = net.addSwitch('of2')
    of3 = net.addSwitch('of3')
    of4 = net.addSwitch('of4')
    of5 = net.addSwitch('of5')

    # Adding hosts
    info('[+] Adding hosts\n')
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', ip='10.0.0.1')
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', ip='10.0.0.2')
    h3 = net.addHost('h3', ip='10.0.0.3')
    h4 = net.addHost('h4', ip='10.0.0.4')
    h5 = net.addHost('h5')
    h6 = net.addHost('h6')
    
    # Adding links based on the diagram (switches connected to each other and hosts)
    info('[+] Adding links between switches, hosts, and edge servers\n')
    # Links between Switches
    net.addLink(of1, of2) # horizontal connection
    net.addLink(of2, of3)
    net.addLink(of4, of5)   
    net.addLink(of1, of4) # Vertical connection 
    net.addLink(of2, of4)
    net.addLink(of3, of5) 
    # Link between Host & Switched
    net.addLink(of1, h1)
    net.addLink(of1, h2)
    net.addLink(of2, h3)
    net.addLink(of2, h4)
    net.addLink(of3, h5)
    net.addLink(of3, h6)
    # Start the network
    net.build()
    c0.start()  # Start the controller
    net.start()

    # Discover the topology
    topology = topology_discovery(net)
    CLI(net)
    net.stop()
    return net, topology

# --------------------------------------- TOPOLOGY DISCOVERY ------------------------------------------
def topology_discovery(net):
    info('[*] Discovering topology\n')
    
    topology = {
        'switches': {},
        'hosts': {},
        'links': []
    }
    
    for switch in net.switches:
        topology['switches'][switch.name] = switch
    
    for host in net.hosts:
        topology['hosts'][host.name] = host
    
    for link in net.links:
        topology['links'].append((link.intf1.node.name, link.intf2.node.name))
    
    print("\n===================================================================================================")
    print("[!] Discovered Topology:")
    print("Switches:", topology['switches'].keys())
    print("Hosts:", topology['hosts'].keys())
    print("Links:", topology['links'])
    print("===================================================================================================")
    
    return topology


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # os.system("mn -c")
    setup_network()

Can anyone tell why the Controller is not sending packets, what is wrong with my mininet network
EDIT:
During research I have found that I need to use STP, there is a STPlib too, but I don't know much if any help about that, it will be a lot of help

There is no image in your question :-(

Added the image, was a formatting error
